# PHP arrays within an array - nested arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm using ACF Pro plugin for Wordpress and use repeater fields.
With this code I get all the field values and additional info in an array:

```
$fields = get_field_object('slideshow');
```

With this code I can narrow it down to what I want to achieve:

```
print_r($fields[value];
```

By now I get this array below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [videoWebm] => /wc/data/uploads/sea.webm
            [videoMp4] => /wc/data/uploads/sea1.mp4
            [text] => Test1
            [kund] => Kund1
            [link1] => 
            [link2] => 
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [videoWebm] => /wc/data/uploads/turntable.webm
            [videoMp4] => /wc/data/uploads/turntable.mp4
            [text] => Test2
            [kund] => Kund2
            [link1] => 
            [link2] => 
        )
)
```

it can grow more - like [2] => Array, [3] => Array etc.

I want to access *all* videoWebm & videoMp4 values.
As of now I know how to access a specific value - for example:

```
print_r($fields[value][0][videoWebm]);
```

But I can't figure out how to access ***all of them*** and put them in two new arrays. One for videoWebm values and one for videoMp4 values. The problem for me is the index value when I try to loop thru the array. I don't know if this really is the way to go...

Anyone suggestions?

Best, Niklas

Comment: `$videoWebms = array_column($array, 'videoWebm');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `foreach`:

```
foreach ($fields[value] as $field) {
    $videoWebms[] = $field['videoWebm']
    $videoMp4s[] = $field['videoMp4'];
}
```

Or as splash58 said, use `array_column`:

```
$vieoWebms = array_column($fields[value], 'videoWebm');
$vieoMp4s = array_column($fields[value], 'videoMp4');
```

I would highly recommend you learn about php's `foreach`, it is very powerful and widely used (maybe a little too widely).

https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20foreach

Answer (score 0):

To get the value from repeater use this :

```
$slides = get_field('slideshow');               
if($slides){
    foreach($slides as $slide){
        echo $slide['videoWebm'];
        echo $slide['text'];
        echo $slide['kund]'];
        echo $slide['link1'];
        echo $slide['link2'];
    }
}
```